# Can Ubuntu Run On Intel Core i5 10th Gen

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, intel-core-i5

I've an Intel Core i5 10th Gen, 8GB RAM and 1TB HDD machine and I want to run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on it. Is it possible?

Comment: It should run fine. The computer seems new and so will have UEFI and Secure Boot and Ubuntu can work with that.

Comment: What research have you done so far? What did you discover to leave you uncertain?

Comment: @Tetsujin He should be very new to the internet....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They comply to the hardware requirements to run Ubuntu 20.04.

**Hardware requirements to run Ubuntu 20.04**

> - 2 GHz dual core processor
> - 4 GiB RAM (system memory)
> - 25 GB (8.6 GB for minimal) of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
> - VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
> - Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
> - Internet access is helpful

I got this information from the link below:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: In the future if you cite a third-party’s material you must also quote that material. Improper citation and quotation of somebody’s written words will be treated as plagiarism. Every school in existence teaches how to property cite and quote the written word from a source.

Comment: This hardly answers the question. The question asks whether a NEW CPU has proper support in Ubuntu. That the hardware in question is generations newer and undoubtedly far more powerful than the minimal requirements doesn't mean it will work well just like that. As a matter of fact, 10th and 11th generations Intel processors have issues with many currently supported Ubuntu and other Linux distros. The newest kernel shipped with Ubuntu (21.10) is strongly recommended.